# Lua heredoc with variable interpolation?

Tags: lua

Is there a way to use a heredoc type of notation in Lua that references variables within the string?

The basic idea of what I'm trying to do would look something like follows.  The heredoc piece is fine, but within Lua you can't actually reference the variable in the manner I'm showing below.

```
username = "bigtunacan"    

sql=[=[
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$bigtunacan';
]=]
```

Comment: @NicolBolas it is a section of a source code file that is treated as if it were a separate file that had been loaded in place. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document

They are often used for multi-line string literals as they are typically clearer than using regular string concatenation for long multi-line strings.

In my sample I have a short string, but that was to simplify for purposes of my question.

Comment: OK, so I should just pretend you said "multiline string literal" then?

Comment: Yes; that's the simplest way to look at it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no built-in string interpolation, but it can be trivially implemented with `gsub` and replacement table.

```
sql=[=[
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username';
]=]

print((sql:gsub('$(%w+)', { username = 'bigtucan' })))
-- SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='bigtucan';
```

Note an extra set of `()` - this is so only first return - the interpolated string is used from `gsub` and the 2nd - number of replacements made - silently discarded. This might be important if you use result of `gsub` as last in list of arguments to some function where adding one more argument might produce different behavior.

Also if you want to use this in SQL context, you really should use placeholders instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Lua construct that allows variable interpolation within any string. See [Literal Strings](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.1) in the official reference guide.

You could of course write a function that would parse it and do the substitutions.